# how to add multiple driver in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am currently writing JDBC Connection code in Java.
I am using the ojdbc11.jar JDBC driver, and I know that the JDBC driver does not support KO16MSWIN949 encoding and causes an error, and I know how to solve it by adding orai18n.jar as a solution.

However, this method can be solved by adding the library when setting the development environment in the IDE, but I want to solve it using a test code example.

I would like to know how to add multiple jars in code.

The Java code where the current error is reproduced is as follows.

```java
public class DBConnInfo {

    public ConnectionDescription getConnectionDescription() {
        ConnectionDescription connectionDesc = new ConnectionDescription();

        connectionDesc.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        connectionDesc.setUser("docker");
        connectionDesc.setPassword("docker");
        connectionDesc.setDriverJarPath("/Users/elvis/JDBC/Oracle/ojdbc8-full/ojdbc11.jar");
        connectionDesc.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        return connectionDesc;
    }

    public void executeSampleQuery(Connection conn) {
        try {
            Statement statement = createStatement(conn);
            
            ResultSet rs = null;
            
            String sql = "SELECT UU.USERNAME \n"
                    + "FROM USER_USERS UU";
            
            rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            
            if(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("USERNAME")); // error : Unsupported character set (add orai18n.jar to classpath): KO16MSWIN949
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

#### ConnectionDescription.java

```java
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConnectionDescription {

    private String url;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String driverJarPath;
    private String driverClassName;

    public ConnectionDescription() {
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDriverJarPath() {
        return this.driverJarPath;
    }

    public void setDriverJarPath(String driverJarPath) {
        this.driverJarPath = driverJarPath;
    }

    public String getDriverClassName() {
        return this.driverClassName;
    }

    public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName) {
        this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
    }

    public Properties getConnectionProperties() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        prop.setProperty("user", this.user);
        prop.setProperty("password", this.password);

        return prop;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ConnectionDescription [url=" + url + ", user=" + user + ", password=" + password + ", driverJarPath="
                + driverJarPath + ", driverClassName=" + driverClassName + "]";
    }
}
```

#### getDriver()

```java
private Driver getDriver(ConnectionDescription desc)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        DriverId driverId = new DriverId(desc.getDriverJarPath(), desc.getDriverClassName());
        Driver driver = this.DRIVERS.get(driverId);

        if (driver == null) {
            ClassLoader parent = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            ClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new URL("file:" + driverId.getJarPath()) },
                    parent);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Class<Driver> driverClass = (Class<Driver>) classLoader.loadClass(driverId.getDriverClassName());

            driver = driverClass.newInstance();

            this.DRIVERS.put(driverId, driver);
        }
        return driver;

    }
```

Comment: It should not be necessary to add the driverjarpath in the code. Only add it to your classpath. BTW: Why you can not only use the *orai18n.jar*

Comment: @Jens As mentioned, I don't want to use the method that applies to the buildpath.

I am in the position of developing a solution, and I cannot ask customers who use this solution to specify a build path. Therefore, I have to modify the code.

Also, there is no way to distribute the library by including the library in the solution.

Comment: But the customer has to copy the file anyway

Comment: Can you shar the package name of ConnectionDescription?

Comment: @Jens We want to communicate with the database by adding jars that the user wants in the UI dialog of the solution, and loading all the added jars.

Like DBeaver for example. The ConnectionDescription class will be written by modifying the body.

Comment: The solution is the same one all SQL tools written in Java have already done (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans, etc.). You can have many JDBC connections, each one having its own driver. The steps are: 1) When initializing the connection, create a (small) new classloader for it that inherits from the main app classloader. 2) Load the JDBC driver from the `driverJarPath` in this classloader. 3) Register the new driver. 4) Now you can open the connection normally. 5) Finally, don't forget to unregister the classloader in your app to free resources, if your app is a long lived one.

Comment: @TheImpaler Can you give me an example? The code that loads the current jdbc driver will be written by modifying the body.

Comment: See [main loader](https://sourceforge.net/p/hotrod/hotrod/ci/maven/tree/attic/hotrod/src/eclipseplugin/java/org/hotrod/eclipseplugin/jdbc/DynamicallyLoadedDriver.java) and [loader](https://sourceforge.net/p/hotrod/hotrod/ci/maven/tree/attic/hotrod/src/eclipseplugin/java/org/hotrod/eclipseplugin/jdbc/SeparateDriverLoader.java). Note that a JDBC driver can be a single jar file (most of the cases) or multiple ones (db2?).